# In an asp.net mvc application, can I use Entity layer as Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layers

I am developing an asp.net mvc solution, which contains the three layers:

- Data Access Layer
- Business Layer
- Entity Layer

Each layer is a project.

I have developed the controllers and views, but no Models. Instead of using Model, I am using the Entity layer as Model.

My question is: Is this still an MVC project?

I attach an image of my solution to better explain my question.

[image]

Comment: Despite the name, the Models directory is meant to be used for ViewModels. Often, a View requires data that is specific to the View itself (think "element is minimized"). These kinds of properties tend to clutter/obfuscate the purpose of objects so they are best segregated into dedicated ViewModels. While you can certainly opt out of using ViewModels, for anything other than a trivial CRUD application you are going to end up polluting your Entities with View state. FWIW, The UI layer is always the most tedious layer to develop.

Comment: Yes, it is still an MVC project.  Your Data Access Layer, Business Layer and 
Entity Layer are all part of the Model.

Answer (score -1):

When you use an entity in a view, in a controller or anywhere, you must use it by namespace. For that reason, It is not important where entities locate.

You can delete **Models** folder and you can put entities in the other project.